"Unknown column 'otp_static_staticdevice.created_at' in 'field list'"
After testing a new release (mfa was working) i got the message :"Unknown column 'otp_static_staticdevice.created_at' in 'field list'".
This normally indicates a new item from a class.
Looking through the django-mfa code i did not found this field.
I suggest it is an automatic generated field.
Added the missing fields to the database. But after that it complaint about an other field (last_created_at) and after adding the fields to another otp table. Then came the error that the field can not be null.
How to get rid of this message.
I solved the problem.
The version of the used python packages used for development (and so the database) were out of sync with the production (docker) versions. (the latest(
After the update of the used python packages and the makemigration and migrate te DB was ok and the  program stopped complaining.
